# Song from Ep 29/ S2 Ep 16 of My Hero Academia starting at 19:21?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

I know I could just go through the OST on YouTube but I get really tired of skimming through so many songs and sometimes I miss the one I'm looking for. I would really appreciate it if someone could find the song for me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is:

> English: Your Power 
>   Japanese: 君の力 (Kimi no chikara)

Its on on the Second OST.

**"My Hero Academia (Anime)" 2nd Original Soundtrack**
 - Track 22